# Set Openbox to be readable on a QHD screen?

Tags: resolution, openbox, dpi, i3-wm

I have a Samsung ATIV Book 9 Plus, which has a Quad HD (3200 x 1800) screen.

Needless to say, the scaling on this make the font super tiny and hard to read. 
In unity it's easy to adjust the window & font scale. However, in openbox or i3 I don't know how... 
Will using xrandr to change the DPI effect the resolution? Can I scale the windows and font to be readable?
 I have tried changing the frame buffer with xrandr but this only lets me use the upper corner of the screen, which is really annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you just look in your .i3/config you'll find the answer:

> Font for window titles. Will also be used by the bar unless a different font
>    is used in the bar {} block below. ISO 10646 = Unicode
>
> > font -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--13-120-75-75-C-70-iso10646-1
>
> The font above is very space-efficient, that is, it looks good, sharp and
>    clear in small sizes. However, if you need a lot of unicode glyphs or
>    right-to-left text rendering, you should instead use pango for rendering and
>    chose a FreeType font, such as:
>
> > font pango:DejaVu Sans Mono 10

If you just choose a larger font, everything becomes more readable:

> > font pango:DejaVu Sans Mono 30

Comment: Thanks, that works. I had to set the font to be 30 to be readable; now the problem is with Chrome. At any rate now I can use 99% of my things, also i3 on this laptop is amazing, much better than openbox.